# responsive autoresponder on iframe

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, auto-responder

I am building an autoresponder for my own website. I thought to put it inside an iframe to decouple it's style from the theme style (i'm  on wordpress), but this gives me two collateral effects.
The first one is that the iframe is not much friendly with the responsiveness, and I'm trying to address it's behaviour to always show the content of the autoresponder.
the second one is that the form inside the iframe has a "thank you" page after the submit, but with the iframe the thank you page will open inside the iframe. 
There is a way to open the thank you page on the host page? Am I doing this the right way? there is maybe a better way to insert a piece of web page in a way that stay indipendent from the theme around it?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use an iframe to de-couple styling to be honest, they can prove far more trouble than they are worth.

I would just override any theme styles I didn't want with CSS targeted at the component. It sounds a lot more involved than it actually would be and you'd have better control over the responsive layout of the component.

Comment: If the theme does not use bootstrap, but I am using bootstrap for my autoresponder, how can I merge them removing the iframe without making a mess?

Comment: @Terix I only have a small amount of bootstrap experience so I can't be sure, but I though most of it's styling is applied through classes (e.g. class="btn btn-primary" for a button or class="col-md-2" for a column width). If you don't apply those class names you won't get any bootstrap styling.

Comment: The other question  I would ask is why do you want part of your page to have a responsive bootstrap style and the rest not to? That isn't going to produce a good user interface to have two or more components that look and behave differently.

Comment: The autoresponder should be theme-agnostic, so I choose bootstrap as framework to simplify my work. If tomorrow I want to change my theme on wordpress, I want to be able to setup my autoresponder again with less work as possible. This is the reason I cannot build my autoresponder on the theme style, and also the reason I went with the iframe to begin with.